AES/GCM : Encrypt in java but unable to decrypt string in dart
I have a server code (Java) which encrypts a string using the below method:
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws Exception {

    byte[] rawKey = key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("key size " + rawKey.length + " key: " + key);
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");

    // Generate a random IV
    byte[] iv = new byte[12];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));

    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    // Combine IV and ciphertext for transmission
    byte[] cipherTextWithIv = new byte[iv.length + encryptedBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, cipherTextWithIv, 0, iv.length);
    System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, cipherTextWithIv, iv.length, encryptedBytes.length);

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherTextWithIv);
}

//Base64 encoded output:
String encrypt = Test.encrypt("I am new to flutter", "mythirtytwolengthlonguniquekey12");

Output: zuaKIqlEBJKVMsqvBb4hfhONkxL9xVyJdezcnS/SSPRswF3P8VfPOJRBKtpvrEs=
Now when I use this output on dart side and try to decrypt it, it prints some gibberish characters.
//dart decrypt logic using 'encrypt: ^5.0.3':
void main() {
final encryptedBase64 = "zuaKIqlEBJKVMsqvBb4hfhONkxL9xVyJdezcnS/SSPRswF3P8VfPOJRBKtpvrEs=";
String uniqueKey = 'mythirtytwolengthlonguniquekey12';

// Extract IV (first 12 bytes)
var ivLength = 12;
final iv = IV.fromBase64(encryptedBase64.substring(0, ivLength));

// Extract ciphertext (remaining bytes)
final cipherText = Encrypted.fromBase64(encryptedBase64.substring(ivLength));

var key = Key.fromUtf8(uniqueKey);
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.gcm, padding: null));

final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(
  cipherText,
  iv: iv,
);
print(decrypted);

}
Output: �qۉ_t�������'�����Ϧ�<��8}'&�e
The secret key and IV are correct. Padding is set to null.
Also I am extracting the IV from the base64 text and decrypting only the cipher text.
What wrong am I doing?

Your decryption logic is based on a false premise: namely the length of base64 encrypted data is the same as its plaintext. It isn't. Decrypt the whole thing and then do the separation

Updated the decryption logic based on the suggestion from goose:
void main() {
final encryptedBase64 = "zuaKIqlEBJKVMsqvBb4hfhONkxL9xVyJdezcnS/SSPRswF3P8VfPOJRBKtpvrEs=";
var decodedString = base64Decode(encryptedBase64);
String uniqueKey = 'mythirtytwolengthlonguniquekey12';

// Extract IV (first 12 bytes)
var ivLength = 12;
final iv = decodedString.sublist(0, ivLength);

// Extract ciphertext (remaining bytes)
// final cipherText = Encrypted.decodedString.substring(ivLength);
final cipherText = decodedString.sublist(12);

var key = Key.fromUtf8(uniqueKey);
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.gcm));

final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(
  Encrypted.fromBase64(base64.encode(cipherText)),
  iv: IV.fromBase64(base64.encode(iv)),
);
print(decrypted);

}
